# Iterate over rows

Tags: r, loops

I know I should be able to find this here, but I am having trouble with R as a beginner. A redirection to where to find an answer would also be very helpful to me, since I looked at a lot of other apply functions but I did not understand them. I have a dataframe 'y' where I want to loop over the rows, and use these row coordinates to get a pvalue from another dataframe 't'. In python you can loop over rows and use the row index. I can also do this in R now, but it is very slow:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(y)) {
  y$pvalue[i] <- min(t$pvalue[t$Start <= y$Start[i] & t$Stop >= y$Stop[i]])
}
```

How would one speed this up with a function like Apply? The syntax really confuses me.

Some play data:

```
t <- data.frame("Chromosome" = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1), "Start" = 
c(0,5,10,15,20,25,30), "Stop" = c(10,15,20,25,30,35,40),"pvalue" = c(0.1,0.4,0.3,0.8,0.6,0.3,0.1))
my_list <- union(t$Start, t$Stop)
y <- data.frame('Start' =my_list[1:length(my_list)-1], "Stop" = my_list[-1])
```

So here we have overlapping coordinates, I am trying to obtain the smallest pvalue from 't' which matches the bins in 'y'.

So it will turn out like:

```
y <- data.frame('Start' =my_list[1:length(my_list)-1], "End" = my_list[-1], "pvalue" = c(0.1,0.1,0.3,0.3,0.6,0.3,0.1,0.1))
```

Comment: With 33pts & 7 questions under your belt (as of this comment) you've been here a while. As such, you likely have seen good questions that provide both representative data and code. Going from klunky for-loop-laden Python to beautifully vectorized R code is not — at first easy — and I'm fairly sure you don't need an R for loop to accomplish this task but having actual data so we can show you a working answer would be super helpful.

Comment: Can you share `y` or at least some part of it? This will make it much easier for others to help you. Use `dput(y)`.

Comment: I edited the question to contain some play data, thanks for looking into it! The main problem for me is the comparison between 2 dataframes

Comment: If you want fast, I would recommend data.table. Something like `library(data.table) ; setDT(t)[setDT(y), min(pvalue), on = .(Start <= Start, Stop >= Stop), by = .EACHI]` should do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `mapply` here

```
y$pvalue <- mapply(function(p, q) min(t$pvalue[t$Start <= p & t$Stop >= q]), 
                                     y$Start, y$Stop)

y
#  Start Stop pvalue
#1     0    5    0.1
#2     5   10    0.1
#3    10   15    0.3
#4    15   20    0.3
#5    20   25    0.6
#6    25   30    0.3
#7    30   35    0.1
#8    35   40    0.1
```